# Referencing common DLL's in nuget package targetting v4 and v4.5

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, versioning

I have a nuget package that includes the DLL build from my project, as well as some supporting 3rd-party DLLs.

This was working previously with an entry in the .nuspec file like this:

```
<files>
    <file src="..\..\Libraries\*.dll" target="lib" />
</files>
```

Nuget would correct reference the 3rd-party libraries as well as the output of my project.
However, I've updated my project to target both .NET v4 and v4.5 - but the 3rd-part DLLs are the same in both cases.

I've changed my nuspec file to this:

```
<files>
    <file src="..\..\Libraries\*.dll" target="lib" />
    <file src="bin\release\4.0\MyProject.dll" target="lib\net40" />
    <file src="bin\release\4.5\MyProject.dll" target="lib\net45" />
</files>
```

and the nuget package contains all the correct files in the correct locations.  However, after installing the package, only "MyProject.dll" is referenced, the 3rd-party DLL's are not.

What do I change `target="lib"` to, to ensure that the DLLs are referenced for all framework versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the third party dlls into both of the lib\net40 and lib\net45 directories.

NuGet will look at the project's target framework and look for a match in the lib directories of the NuGet package. When it finds a match it will only add references to the dlls in that specific lib directory. So a .NET 4.0 project would only have references added to the dlls in the lib\net40 directory.

Comment: thanks, that is indeed what I ended up doing.  Was hoping for something better as that doubles the size of the package, but at least it works.